# How to read multi line multi string registry entry in Visual C++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, registry

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I am working in vc++ mfc application.
I want to know how to read multi line string value from registry.Here type `REG_MULTI_SZ` indicates A sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string (\0).
So far I am able to read only first line. Give me Idea about how I can read multi string at once.
Thanks
[image]

I tried Something like this

```
HKEY hKey;
CString RegPath = _T("SOFTWARE\\...\\...\\");   //Path
if(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,RegPath,0,KEY_READ|KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS|KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,&hKey))
{
    DWORD nBytes,dwType = REG_MULTI_SZ;
    CString version;
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::RegQueryValueEx(hKey,_T("Options"),NULL,&dwType,0,&nBytes))
    {
        ASSERT(REG_MULTI_SZ == dwType);
        LPTSTR buffer = version.GetBuffer(nBytes/sizeof(TCHAR));
        VERIFY(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::RegQueryValueEx(hKey,_T("Options"),NULL,0,(LPBYTE)buffer,&nBytes));
        AfxMessageBox(buffer);     //Displaying Only First Line
        version.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
::RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Then it' will be mich easier for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your multi string consists of two strings "AB" and "CD".

The layout in memory is like this:

```
+--------+
|  'A'   |   <-- buffer  // first string
+--------+
|  'B'   |
+--------+
|   0    |    // terminator of first string
+--------+
|  'C'   |    // second string
+--------+
|  'D'   |
+--------+
|   0    |    // terminator of second string
+--------+
|   0    |    // terminator of multi string
+--------+
```

Therefore `AfxMessageBox(buffer)` displays only the first string.

You shouldn't read the multi string into a `CString`, because `CString` only deals with nul terminated strings. You should read the multi string into a `TCHAR` buffer and then parse that buffer in order to extract the individual strings.

Basically:

```
 ASSERT(REG_MULTI_SZ == dwType);
 LPTSTR buffer = new TCHAR[nBytes / sizeof(TCHAR)];
 VERIFY(ERROR_SUCCESS == ::RegQueryValueEx(hKey,_T("Options"),NULL,0,(LPBYTE)buffer,&nBytes));

 CStringArray strings;
 const TCHAR *p = buffer;
 while (*p)               // while not at the end of strings
 {
   strings.Add(p);        // add string to array
   p += _tcslen(p) + 1 ;  // find next string
 }

 delete [] buffer;

 // display all strings (for debug and demonstration purpose)
 for (int i = 0; i < strings.GetCount(); i++)
 {
   AfxMessageBox(strings[i]);
 }

 // now the strings array contains all strings
```

Comment: That is what I want to know, How to find next strings? As in example shown by you how can I get string `CD`.

Comment: Sorry to say but m still getting same result. It is showing only first line.

Comment: Of course, **you** must parse `buffer`. `AfxMessageBox` stops at the first NUL character, so in my example it will display only "AB".

Comment: See my edited answer. You should get some basics of C/C++/MFC.

Comment: It is showing some Conversion errors, After Solving this issue I will get back.

Comment: I did'nt compile that code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Why are you mixing `TCHAR` and `char`? And your `delete buffer` is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you are right, as I said, it's not tested neither I tried to compile. I've corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: Some problem is there in `p += _tcslen(p) + 1 ;` I tried `_mbstrlen` in that place. Now first string it is showing correct After that it is showing some different characters.

Comment: Try `wcslen` or `strlen` instead of `_tcslen` You should be able to sort this out with the debugger.

Comment: The code in my answer works here perfectly both with the Unicode Character Set ans with the Multi-Byte Character Set.

Comment: Do be careful with `RegQueryValueEx()`, it does not ensure the data is null-terminated properly, it reads the data as-is and requires the original writer to have saved proper nulls. To ensure proper nulls regardless of the original data, use `RegGetValue()` instead.

Comment: I'm also doing the same thing but why in my PC it is not working. Only first line m getting correct.